# Conditional Compilation for Android/Java

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am looking for a methodology by which I can skip certain lines of codes in java/android. For example

```
class Test{

    void initVersion(){
    }

    void initVersion1(){
    }

}
```

So if I have a settings I should tell the compiler to skip certain method while compiling for certain version.

I know that we can use gradle's product flavor by which you can use different class for different version. However I want the same class file for both the version but some of the methods have to be skipped.

Comment: And how you would use it later?

Comment: When I compile a .java file it should skip certain methods it can be based on some annotation or some other ways. So for example in android we have two res for different versions. One version will have Button other version will have ImageView instead of Button. So I should skip the method which uses the button method initialization for one version and use ImageView method.

Comment: It doesn't make sens ... `interface ITest void initVersion()` .... then buid  classes `TestImpl` and `TestImpl1` which are implementing `ITest` ... then choose an implementation ...`ITest IMPL = new TestImpl()` or  `ITest IMPL = new TestImpl1()` ...

Comment: "So if I have a settings I should tell the compiler to skip certain method while compiling for certain version" -- if the method being skipped is being called, the result is that your code will not compile. The only way that this could possibly work is if the skipped code is only used via reflection, which tends to be slow and less maintainable. I recommend that you find some other solution.

Comment: void initVersion1(){
EditText name = (Edittext) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.edtName); // this id (edtName) is for version1
}
void initVersion2(){
Button name = (Button) mRootView.findViewById(R.id.btnName); //this id (btnName) is for version2
}

I have both the above methods on a java file. Now I use two res for version1 and version2. If I compile for version1 compiler will complaint it will not find the id btnName.
So if i can skip the method initVersion2, the compiler will not complain about the missing id.

Comment: Check gradle flavors or build variants https://developer.android.com/studio/build/build-variants.html

Comment: gradle flavors or build variants can have different java classes for different version I agree, however my case is compiler ignoring few methods on a single java file at compile time based on flavours. Do gradle or java support this type of compilation.